# is there an option to configure replication salve of MYSQL version 5.7 to master Azure Database for MySQL of version 5.6?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

i have Azure Database for MySQL of version 5.6  in AZURE and i read somewhere that MYSQL support in slave in higher version (5.7) than the master (5.6) but i did not found any reference to it in AZURE doc and did not found any option to configure version when creating replica via AZURE portal , is this possible to configure replica in higher version specifically salve of MYSQL version 5.7 to MYSQL 5.6 master in Azure Database for MySQL  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Database for MySQL support version 5.6 and 5.7.

You can get all the supported versions and  release notes from this document:
[Supported Azure Database for MySQL server versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-supported-versions):

1. MySQL Version 5.6: Refer to the MySQL [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-44.html) to learn
   more about improvements and fixes in this version.
2. MySQL Version 5.7: Refer to the MySQL [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-26.html) to learn
   more about improvements and fixes in this version.

In Azure Database for MySQL,Using dump and restore help you upgrade across MySQL versions. For more details, please see: [Common uses for dump and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-migrate-dump-restore#common-uses-for-dump-and-restore)

To avoid any compatibility issues, ensure the same version of MySQL is used on the source and destination systems when dumping databases. For example, if your existing MySQL server is version 5.7, then you should migrate to Azure Database for MySQL configured to run version 5.7.

If you don't need to care about the compatibility issues, you can try to use this way to 
downgrade and configure the version 5.7 to 5.6.

Hope this helps.